# Altering multiple MySQL database tables at the same time

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I normally use phpMyAdmin for any database changes therefore rarely delve into making changes to schema via MySQL queries. I now however have multiple databases all exactly the same and it would be a huge time saver if I could alter all databases at the same time. I can use the following code for a single database

```
ALTER demo_database.demo_table ADD another_demo_column VARCHAR(255) AFTER demo_column_index
```

but I'm curious if I can use similar code like the following which obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be asking the question.

```
ALTER demo_database.demo_table, demo_database_2.demo_table ADD another_demo_column VARCHAR(255) AFTER demo_column_index
```

I know I could obviously duplicate the same line of code over and over for each table but it would be good if there is a more elegant solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL documentation for [ALTER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) you cannot combine the same alter statements across multiple tables.

You can however combine multiple alter statements to the same table.

If you had a lot to do then a stored procedure with prepared statements would be more elegant than copying and pasting.